# cpp private data member SDL_Rect inactive

Tags: c++, class, sdl

I have a 7 x 7 matrix of probes that deliver a signal representing the level measured at that point in the area under investigation.  I can draw a matric of 7 x 7 rectangles in SDL but I was unable to update the color.
I have a class 
class Probe 
    { 
    public: 
        Probe(); 
        ~Probe(); 
        void SetColor(int x); 
        void Set_id(int x, int y, int z);
        void Level_id(void);

```
private: 
    int OldColor; 
    int Xcord; 
    int Ycord; 
    SDL_Rect rect; //This does not keep the rect that I create?
};
//outside all curly brackets {} I have 
Probe Level[7][7];
//I initialize each instance of my class 
Level[x][y].Set_id(x, y, z); and I use x and y to create and position the rectangle
//  Defininlg rectangles
    SDL_Rect rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
/*I get what I expected, by the way z sets the color and it is incremented so each rectangle has a      different color. */

//I used function SetColor, it failed untill I regenerated rect
//in the SetColor function.  I have
private:
SDL_Rect rect;
//It is private why do I need to re-create the SDL_Rect rect?
//Why is it not stored like 
private:
int Xcord; // !!?  Regards Ian.
```

Comment: //I understand.
    SDL_Rect rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
    //Defines a new rect local to the function.
    rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
    //uses the rect defined in the class as private: and is global to the
    //class.
    //Many thank Ian.

Comment: rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
// rect.x = BLOCK_W * Xcord;
// rect.y = BLOCK_H * Ycord;  //These all cause a segment fault.

Comment: // I put this in the constructor and SetColor updates rect[0][0]

Comment: //This is an awkward tool to use, pls excuse the mess I've made.
//rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
// rect.x = BLOCK_W * Xcord;
// rect.y = BLOCK_H * Ycord;  //These all cause a segment fault.
// I put this in the constructor and SetColor updates rect[0][0];
Probe::Probe() {
 rect = {0, 0, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
}  //I seem able to acces rect but not change it.  Ian.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your class looks something like this:

```
class Probe {
public:
   Probe();
   ~Probe();

   void SetColor(int x);
   void Set_id(int x, int y, int z) {
      SDL_Rect rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
   }
private:
   int OldColor; 
   int Xcord; 
   int Ycord; 
   SDL_Rect rect;
};
```

and you're wondering why the "rect" variable won't save as the private one, and how you change the color when drawing an SDL_Rect?

First of all, your "rect" isn't getting saved because you are defining a new "rect" variable in your function. What you should do is either of these:

```
rect = {BLOCK_W * Xcord, BLOCK_H * Ycord, BLOCK_W, BLOCK_H};
```

or

```
rect.x = BLOCK_W * Xcord;
rect.y = BLOCK_H * Ycord;
rect.w = BLOCK_W;
rect.h = BLOCK_H;
```

And to change the color of the rendering (assuming you are using the SDL_RenderDrawRect function, as that is the only one I know of that you can draw SDL_Rects with), you simply call:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(int r, int g, int b, int a);
```

right before you call the SDL_RenderDrawRect function (every time).
If you do not do this, and call the SetRenderDrawColor function somewhere else, your color will change to that color.